# Notifications say that a friend commented, but no comment is visible

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, when I open the comments of a post that says "Friend A commented on this," it will open up 4 comments, with an option to show more.

How come sometimes, one of those four comments will be the one my friend made (which is ultimately the one I want to see), and sometimes none of those four will be?

As a side note, how are those 4 comments decided? Often times, they are not the most upvoted comments.

Answer (score 1):

You must look at all the comments not only first four comments. "Friend A commented on this" doesn't mean it is going to show on top or in first few comments. It means your friend A has commented on some post and your are getting notify on your news feed because you are following your friend. You have to search friend's comment in all comments.

How will comments show it depends on settings of the poster.

Comment: Yes, but it does display my friend's comment far too often for the four comments to be completely random